# How to encode array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I encode javascript arrays in url?

eg: The following is my query param

```
/query?colors=['red','blue','green',]
```

expected output

```
%5B%27red%27%2C%27blue%27%2C%27green%27%2C%5D
```

I've tried encodeURI and encodeURIComponent, but the comma is not getting transformed in to %2C.

**UPDATE**
I tried this

```
let colors = ['red','green']
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(colors))
```

colors=%255B%2522red%2522%252C%2522green%2522%255D.

But when I does so additional characters 25 is getting added. How Can I prevent that?

Comment: It’s not necessary to encode the comma. Is it a problem that it’s not getting encoded…?

Comment: Ýes. It is a problem, if comma is not encoded. API won't return anything. So comma must be encoded.

Comment: You must be double encoding something there somewhere. That code does not add "%25"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
let urlSearch = new URLSearchParams()
urlSearch.set("colors",JSON.stringify(['red','blue','green']))
console.log("/query?"+urlSearch.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = ['red','blue','green'];

console.log('colors='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(test)));
```

Comment: colors=%255B%2522red%2522%252C%2522green%2522%255D.

But when I does so additional characters 25 is getting added. How Can I prevent that?